# Detect if jquery ajax response is JSON or binary and, if it is the latter, download file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to get and download a xslx file from a PHP script. The script can have two kind of response types: in JSON format if there is some warning that prevent download (eg: wrong parameters) or the xlsx binary stream if everything is alright.

The switch works fine: if response is JSON I can parse it and show warnings. But if it is a stream, although the file is actually downloaded, Excel can't open it, because it says it's corrupted. The file content seems normal (it begins with PK and so on), but obviously something is wrong.

What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'download_xlsx.php',
    cache: false,
    type: 'post',
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (resp, text, xhr)
    {
        // Response in JSON format
        if (xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == 'application/json')
        {
            console.log('JSON Response, must be something wrong in parameters. No download, show warnings');
        }

        // Binary stream
        else
        {
            console.log("Xlsx file stream, must download");

            // Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
            var blob = new Blob([resp], { type: "application/octetstream" });
            var fileName = 'output.xlsx';

            // Check the Browser type and download the File.
            var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
            if (isIE)
            {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = $("<a />");
                a.attr("download", fileName);
                a.attr("href", link);
                $("body").append(a);
                a[0].click();
                a.remove();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck using https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ than trying to implement this yourself. Technically browsers don't explicitly support saving files to a user's computer via javascript and you may be running into URL size restrictions(A data uri has no guarantees about max size). The expectation is you should make an actual request from the browser for the file. The download attribute on anchors is useful in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Deadron, I tried FileSaver.js and it works as expected, it makes it easy to download the blob as file and that's great. Unluckily, the file is corrupted the same way it was simulating the download via URI. I think the problem is the blob itself instead of the download method used